# writing spring RESTful end point using java 1.4

Tags: spring

Is there any way to develop spring based restful end point using jdk1.4(non annotation base approach because java 1.4 won't support) ?

I have oc4j server(oracle application server) version 10.1.3 which supports j2sdk 1.4 and servlet 2.4. I believe I won't be able to deploy a springboot restful web service in my oc4j server because of jdk1.4(minimum java version required for springboot is 1.6)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree Spring Boot is not possible for my scenario. I am asking if it is possible to develop spring web-mvc using jdk 1.4 and servlet 2.4 version ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the XML based configurations for initializing spring context. A RESTful application can be built even without using Spring using Jersey or some other JAX-RS implementations, if you are not going to use any Spring capabilities.